# initramfs - ERROR: device '/dev/mapper/vg0-root' not found, Skipping fsck

Tags: arch-linux, initramfs, mkinitcpio

Upon booting my Dell XPS 15 9560 running Arch, I am being dropped into an emergency shell because my devices aren't being found

```
starting version 239

A password is required to access the luks volume:
mount: /new_root: special device /dev/mapper/vg0-root does not exist.
ERROR: device '/dev/mapper/vg0-root' not found, Skipping fsck.
mount: /new_root: special device /dev/mapper/vg0-root does not exist.
You are now being dropped into an emergency shell.
sh: can't access tty; job control turned off
[rootfs ]#
```

Output of `lvm pvs`

```
[rootfs ]# lvm pvs
  WARNING: Not using lvmetad bacause config setting use_lvmetad=0
  WARNING: To avoid corruption, rescan devices to make changes visible (pvscan --cache)
  PV               VG  Fmt  Attr PSize    PFree
  /dev/mapper/luks vg0 lvm2 a--  <237.74g    0
```

Output of `lvm lvs`

```
[rootfs ]# lvm lvs
  WARNING: Not using lvmetad bacause config setting use_lvmetad=0
  WARNING: To avoid corruption, rescan devices to make changes visible (pvscan --cache)
  LV   VG  Attr       LSize    Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  root vg0 -wi------- <221.74g
  swap vg0 -wi-------   16.00g
```

That output is really confusing because it shows that vg0-root and vg0-swap both exist, but they just don't appear under dev, including after doing a `cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme0n1p3 luks`

My guess would be that I'm missing a hook with my mkinitcpio.conf, but this is my mkinitcpio.conf

```
HOOKS=(base udev autodetect modconf block encrypt lvm2 filesystems keyboard fsck)
```

Which I don't believe is any different from 5 days ago, the last time it booted just fine. I did run a `pacman -Syu` earlier today, but I'm not sure how I would find out what exactly broke here.

`mkinitcpio -p linux` works without errors when chrooted into the drive from a arch usb

edit:

added `root=/dev/mapper/luks` to my `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`, and now get the error `mount: /new_root: unknown filesystem type LVM2_member'`

`lvm vgchange -ay vg0`

`mount /dev/mapper/vg0-root /new_root`

`exit`

Allowed me to boot into my system, but this should be happening automatically with the lvm2 hook and upon restarting, I have to do it again.

Comment: From the chroot, read your pacman.log for the update. Also, check the output of `pacman -Q linux && uname -r`.

Comment: I was on 14.18.10, downgraded to 14.18.5 to check if it was a kernel issue, but the issue remains after downgrading to the last kernel it worked on.

I have found a bandaid fix that I've added to the bottom of the OP if that gives any insight into what the issue is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did to fix this

Switched to systemd initramfs by changing all busybox hooks to their systemd equivalents, and changed the grub `DEFAULT_CMDLINE_LINUX` to reflect the syntax of sd-encrypt and sd-lvm2.

I then reset my lvm.conf

`sudo rm /etc/lvm/lvm.conf && sudo pacman -S lvm2`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, the logical volumes were showing as inactive while doing `lvscan`.

The only change I did before in the `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf` was to disable `use_lvmetad`.

To recover from this scenario I have ran:

```
rm /etc/lvm/lvm.conf && pacman -S lvm2
```

but I think it is worth trying to re-enable `use_lvmetad` and regenerate ram disk:

So:

1. make sure the `use_lvmetad=1` in `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf`
2. if you are changing the option to `use_lvmetad=1` , regenerate ramdisk:

   ```
   mkinitcpio -p linux
   ```